# transfer data from Excel Online

Tags: excel, database

I want to transfer data from Excel Online to another Excel Online and continuous transfer

In Excel Online, there is no such function. I hope you suggest solutions to this problem

I used copying, pasting and direct linking, but when sharing the file, the link stops because I share the second file with the team, and the main file is with me only so that no one can modify or tamper with it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.